# PHP never-repeating Random Number

Tags: php, mysql, random, numbers

I need to create a completely random number for each user on my website and insert it into a MySQL database. The numbers can never repeat and I don't want to use MySQL AutoIncrement because I need a specific range. Say from `111,111` to `999,999,999,999`. No higher or lower as of right now. I do have a specific reason for that range, incase you were wondering. I know I can use the `unique` feature on MySQL but that only prevents me from inserting duplicates. I was thinking of having 2 functions, one to generate the number, and another to check if that number is used. They would keep looping until they found a number that wasn't used. I know how inefficient that is and how long it may take once majority of those numbers have been taken so that is why I have come here, for a better answer. What do you suggest I do because I am all out of ideas. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Will you really be using up "most" of the numbers in the range?

Comment: Why must it be random?  Can it just auto increment within that range?

Comment: Totally off the wall and no idea if this would work but something like... `Select random from myTable where random not exists (Select ID from myTable) limit 1`

Comment: The efficiency of a (guess, then check) algorithm to generate a unique number depends entirely on how full your number range is.  If you really have, say, 999 billion possible numbers, and only use 1 million, you'll very rarely get collisions, so it should work fine.

Comment: Slight nitpick... If it can't repeat then it's not "completely random."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we will make it possible to generate any value in the closed interval [111111,999999999999], then we merely need to find some integer that is relatively prime to

```
999999999999 - 111111 + 1 = 999999888889
```

This a composite number, with rather large factors {18181, 55002469}.

So now build a simple, not terribly random (but surely adequate here) number generator that will generate a new pseudo-random integer from the last one chosen. Do that by a simple modular computation. Pick some number to start with, and another integer that is relatively prime to the factors listed above.

```
N(1) = 111111111111
N(i+1) = mod(N(i)*2803 + 4353454321 , 999999888889)
```

You can repeat this process without cycling until you get very bored.

Since you want the lower limit to be 111111, just add that value to every number when you use it. This procedure yields the following sequence:

```
{111111111111, 448832453975, 81861723884, 462790945592, 207518059664, 677539248004, 147076609322, 260135161619, 163292472297, 713204080539, 115613316027, 68514277966, ...}
```

You will add 111111 to every value to ensure that the lower limit is truly 111111, so the sequence that will be reported is just:

```
{111111222222, 448832565086, 81861834995, 462791056703, 207518170775, 677539359115, 147076720433, 260135272730, 163292583408, 713204191650, 115613427138, 68514389077, ...}
```

The nice thing is all you need to be able to do is store the last member of the sequence, and do modular operations on a number that will fit into a 64 bit integer.

Answer (score 6):

You know you can just:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` AUTO_INCREMENT=111111
```

Right?

Anyway, if you're still bent on randomness, it's probably most efficient to `SELECT` all the existing values, load them in a PHP array, then have PHP call `rand(111111,999999999999)` until you get a number that is not `in_array`.

Side-note: PHP cannot handle 999,999,999,999 unless it is the 64-bit version, because that number is too high for 32-bits.

Comment: I have already looked into it, it is the 64 bit version. I made sure of that before I posted.

Comment: +1.  Same base solution as me (24 seconds faster though) and explaining that selecting all into an array and choosing randomly out of that array is *way* more efficient.  Also, good mention of problems if not on 64bit PHP.

Comment: Quick question, is there any way to make it so only 1 field has an auto_increment value starting at 111111, the others start at 1? I'm sorry if this is an easy question, i'm not the best at MySQL code yet. Thanks for this though, perfect answer!

Comment: It seems like reading into an array would not scale. One approach I've seen, for the inverse, is to generate N random numbers and then use those in a select to see which have not been used with a `SELECT` (on indices, of course). A `LIMIT` could help the query planner.

Comment: The way @Kolink wrote it will only affect the one table.

Comment: @sberry I meant to write column. How do I use that code so only one column's auto_incremment feature will start at 111111, the others start at 1? Thanks!

Comment: You can only have one `auto_increment` per table.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting the auto increment number to 1111111.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable AUTO_INCREMENT=1111111;
```